# JAX-RS Accept Images as input

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

For quite some time now, I've been developing JAX-RS web services for my development needs. All the methods that I've written so far accept java Strings or primitive types as input.

An example of such a method:

```
@POST  
@Path("MyMethod")  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public String MyMethod(@FormParam("username")String username, @FormParam("password")String passowrd)
```

What I'm trying to do now is accept images as input. I read a lot of articles regarding this. Some suggested accepting the base64 encoding as input and others suggested accepting an actual InputSteam.

However, i'm yet to see a full blown example on how to accept an InputStream. I read about the @consumer annotation and @Provider but i still can't wrap my head around it. Is there an article, documentation or an example that somehow guides me toward this? i.e. A step by step process on how to implement rather than displaying theory.

I know that the base64 encoding works but out of curiosity i would like to know how the other approach works as well...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
@POST
@Path("MyMethod") 
@Consumes("*/*") // to accept all input types 
public String MyMethod(InputStream stream) {
    byte[] image = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
    return "done";
}
```

Comment: I didn't try the code above, but what if i want to have more than one parameter? A series of Strings and primitive types AND an InputStream? Also what if i want to support all types of images?

Comment: How do you want your HTTP POST request body to look like?

Comment: yegor256, I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean how i'll be constructing my request body?

Comment: How are you going to combine `InputStream` with `String` parameters? Give an example of a POST request body

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the preferred but a simple way to combine `InputStream` with one or more path parameters:

```
@POST
@Path("page/{page}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Produces("image/jpeg")
public StreamingOutput generatePage(final InputStream inputStream, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    final int page = Integer.parseInt(uriInfo.getPathParameters().getFirst("page"));
    return (outputStream) -> {
        service.generatePage(page, inputStream, outputStream);
    };
}
```