# REST File uploading - multipart or just sending content on inputstream

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I need to write REST resource that should receive a file and save it to the disk.
The files will be sent from jersey client.
For now, I see two options:
1. Using multipart
2. Just reading the inputstream as a string and saving it to a file.

What are the pros of using multipart? is it related to file size? or anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Jersey server side, using multipart you gain

- disk buffering (surely you don't want to retain huge files in memory)
- automatic base64/binary stream conversion

If you choose the String option these benefits are unavailable.

See also my answer to the question [JAX-RS Accept Images as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858321/jax-rs-accept-images-as-input), there is a sample implementation of the multipart option

Comment: If I implement using multipart, does it meas that the client side will also buffer the file in the memory?

Comment: Since you are useing JErsey, try `StreamDataBodyPart`