# Jersey Upload file

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am using this code to upload a file using jersey

```
@Path(value="/file")
public class upload {
@POST
@Path(value = "/upload/{path}")
@Consumes("image/png")
public Response uploadPng(@PathParam("path") String path, File file) throws IOException     {
    file = new File("C://Users/Marwa/Desktop/"+ path);
    String uploadedFileLocation = "C:/Users/Marwa/Desktop/workspace/" + file.getName();
    DataInputStream diStream =new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    long len = (int) file.length();
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int) len];
    int read = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (read < fileBytes.length && (numRead =diStream.read(fileBytes, read,fileBytes.length - read)) >= 0) {
    read = read + numRead;
    }
    writeToFile(diStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    System.out.println("File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation);
    return Response.status(200).entity(file).build();
    }
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                         String uploadedFileLocation) {
    try {
        OutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}}}
```

When I execute it (http://$$$$:8080/Ws/rest/files/upload/sms.png) I am getting nothing .Are there any suggestions to this issue ?? I don't know whether there is an error in my code or  the way I call the web-service is wrong !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAX-RS Accept Images as input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858321)

Comment: It is not the same !! in the example of this link, the image to add is added from a html form. Thanks anyway

Comment: There are two answers with working examples how to upload a file. For them it doesn't matter if the client uses a HTML form or curl. In your example it's not clear how you upload the file. What do you mean with "execute it"? Your code looks more like you are copying a file on the server.